# How to apply filter to local maxima (plot)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Following code lets me plot trc-oscilloscope data. In addition I am marking the local maxima and minima of the plot.

trc-file: https://ufile.io/0zd2c (200MB)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import readTrc
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from scipy import signal

#100mil datapoints
datX, datY, m = readTrc.readTrc('C220180104_ch2_UHF00014.trc')
srx, sry = pd.Series(datX * 1000), pd.Series(datY * 1000)
df = pd.concat([srx, sry], axis = 1)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

#Impulse location
x1 = df[1].idxmax() - 0.0005
x2 = df[1].idxmax() + 0.003
df2 = df.loc[x1:x2]

#Locate Maximum
print('Maximum at:', round(df[1].idxmax(), 6), 'ms')

#Local Maxima
n=10 #Every n maximum a Point will be placed
df3_min = df2.iloc[argrelextrema(df2[1].values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]][1]
df3_max = df2.iloc[argrelextrema(df2[1].values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]][1]
plt.scatter(df3_min.index, df3_min, c='r')
plt.scatter(df3_max.index, df3_max, c='g')

#Plot Impulse
df2[1].plot(grid = 1,
        linewidth = 1,
        figsize = (9,5),
        color = 'blue',
        legend = False,
        xlim = (x1, x2))

plt.xlabel('Time in ms')
plt.ylabel('UHF-Signal in mV')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Now I want to put a curve through the maxima. How would I do that? I tried to use filters, but they "cut off" the highest extreme (maximum).

Edit:

adding these code connects maxima:

```
df3_max.plot()
```

Output:

[image]

Now if I try to apply a butter filter:

```
b, a = signal.butter(5, 0.1)
y2 = signal.filtfilt(b,a, df3_max[1].values)
df3_max = pd.DataFrame(y2, index=df3_max.index)
```

I get an Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 379, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 385, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1.0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artur/Desktop/shard_plot/UHF_impulse_plot.py", line 38, in <module>
    y2 = signal.filtfilt(b,a, df3_max[1].values)
  File "/home/artur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 767, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/home/artur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py", line 358, in get_value
    loc = self.get_loc(k)
  File "/home/artur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/numeric.py", line 419, in get_loc
    tolerance=tolerance)
  File "/home/artur/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 379, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 385, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1.0
```

Comment: Does `plot` function not do what you need? `plt.plot(df3_max.index, df3_max)` or even `df3_max.plot()`? I may not be understanding the problem though.

Comment: In addition to `plt.scatter(df3_max.index, df3_max, c='g')` you can plot `plt.plot(df3_max.index, df3_max, c='g')` . Does that already solve it or do you mean some spline fit through your maxima?

Comment: df3_max is a dataframe filled with None except the maxima. I had to this because the maxima that I want to plot (circles) had to have the same index as the base df.

Comment: You probably want to plot `df3_max.dropna().plot()`?

Comment: @busybear I am sorry, my question is very misleading. What I am looking for is basically this in addition with a butter filter.

Comment: I don't know the format of your dataframe, but it seems that you just need `df3_max` instead of `df3_max[1]`.

Comment: Well, that helped. Thank you

Comment: @busybear: you might want to add this as an answer :)

Comment: I guess that would help to get the question marked as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot` method for your maxima, `df3_max`, should do the trick:

```
df3_max.plot()
```

To apply the filter, you can use the `scipy.signal.butter` function for a lowpass filter.

```
b, a = signal.butter(5, 0.1)
y2 = signal.filtfilt(b, a, df3_max.values)
df3_max_filt = pd.DataFrame(y2, index=df3_max.index)

df3_max_filt.plot()
```